# Appending two lists with many elements in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

The following code gives me `A` for `i=1,2`. But then I want `A` for each `i` to append and give combined `A` i.e. for both `i=1,2`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A=[]

for i in range(1,3):
    file_loc = f"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\{i}\\Test.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
    A=df["N"].to_numpy()
    
    A = [x for x in A if str(x) != 'nan']
    
    A = [eval(e) for e in A]
    print([A])
```

The current output is

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
[[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]],[[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append `[A]` to some other array within each iteration, and print the array containing both arrays in the end

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = []
X = []

for i in range(1,3):
    file_loc = f"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\{i}\\Test.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
    A=df["N"].to_numpy()
    
    A = [x for x in A if str(x) != 'nan']
    
    A = [eval(e) for e in A]
    X.append([A])

print(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

I change your code with remove misisng values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and `ast.literal_eval` for avoid [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), then create new list `B` and append to `out` list:

```
import ast

out,B=[],[]

for i in range(1,3):
    file_loc = f"C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive - Technion\\Research_Technion\\Python_PNM\\Sept12_2022\\{i}\\Test.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_loc, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A,C:AA")
    
    B = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df["N"].dropna()]
    out.append(B)

print(out)
```